# executing the constructor of a class in Java

Tags: java, constructor

there is a constructor in my Booking class as below:

```
public Booking (String name, String phone, int [] adultSeats, int [] childSeats )
{
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;

    this.adultSeats = adultSeats;
    this.childSeats = childSeats;

}
```

I would like to write a Tester class for executing the constructor by creating Booking object.

I have made a lot  of tries such as:

Try1 : `Booking b1 = new Booking ("Ali","32788943",{0,1},{3,4,5}) ;`

Try2 : `Booking b1 = new Booking ("Ali","32788943",2,3) ;`

**How can I execute the constructor in the Tester class?**

Thanks.

Comment: Try `Booking b1 = new Booking ("Ali","32788943",new int[]{0,1},new int[]{3,4,5});` And read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: On the other hand, do you really need to test this method? Writing a test that only checks for correct field assignments is rather pointless ...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My aim calling the methods such as                      b1.getNumberOfAdults(); 
b1.getNumberOfChildren();                                             but I was getting error when I was creating Booking object. Thanks to your comments the problem is sorted out

Answer (score 5):

If you want to specify a new array inline (in the call to any constructor or method), you have to create it explicitly and specify its type like so:

```
Booking b1 = new Booking ("Ali","32788943",new int[]{0,1},new int[]{3,4,5});
```

In this case, simply specifying `{3,4,5}` isn't enough to satisfy the compiler, since potentially ambiguous cases could arise about the array type (since, unlike with generics, array types are reified, not erased).

If you want to avoid this inline notation, then breaking it out into separate variables may be clearer:

```
int[] adultSeats = {0,1};
int[] childSeats = {3,4,5};
Booking b1 = new Booking("Ali", "32788943", adultSeats, childSeats);
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My aim calling the methods such as                      b1.getNumberOfAdults(); 
b1.getNumberOfChildren();                                             but I was getting error when I was creating Booking object. Thanks to your comments the problem is sorted out

Answer (score 0):

You should pass **int** type array values for **adultSeats** and **childSeats**

Make it as

```
Booking b1 = new Booking ("Ali","32788943",new int[]{0,1},new int[]{3,4,5});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
Booking b1 = new Booking("Ali", "32788943", new int[] {0, 1}, new int[] {3, 4, 5});
```